# Permutation Diagram Proof??

Tags: permutations, proof-explanation

I was recently watching this video on YouTube

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qTx98PUW6lE

At timestamp 1:19:05 the lecturer starts talking about a diagramatic representation of permutations that can be represented by connecting three numbers to black/white vertices ( the black/white colour changes the direction of the permutation). He goes on to state that there is a proof that all permutations can be constructed by combining these two basic elements together.

Unfortunately he does not mention the name of this type of representation of permutations. I have tried searching all combinations of keywords I can think of but I can't find more information on this proof, or even this general way of representing permutations.

Could anyone point me in the direction of a website/paper that outlines this proof? I would also be interested to find a resource that talks in detail about this type of representation of permutations. Even the proper name of this type of permuration theory would really help me to find the info I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a starting point: https://books.google.hu/books?id=5sHgCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=permutations+diagram+left+and+right+turn&source=bl&ots=yfd_g-tRva&sig=ACfU3U0m1XnFktRO8MwxJoWoAbu3LFLj1A&hl=hu&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj1Zb36JXnAhWn_CoKHdpMCQEQ6AEwFXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=permutations%20diagram%20left%20and%20right%20turn&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou Berci for that suggestion I was able to find through the references of that book the proof I was looking for. It is in this paper by Postnikov.

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609764

Also this type of permutation representation is called 'plabic networks' or 'plabic graphs'.

I look forward to reading the paper!